# C++, buffer carrying stored statement using Ctrl+C

Tags: c++, buffer, copy-paste, ctrl

I want to make a simple windows32 console application using c++ that takes what is stored in the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> buffer and copies it in a char array or a string.

Example: I select the word "Hello", I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then the program put the word "Hello" (stored in the buffer) in a char array.

Comment: Splendid idea?? Was there a *question*? Or were you just looking for a link to the [Windows Clipboard API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468801(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't know if you are kidding, but I think the OP wants to copy the text that is on the clipboard.

Comment: Yes @Massa, exactly what you told.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> is not sent as a normal keystroke like most other <kbd>CTRL-key</kbd> combinations, that's because <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> is the *break* signal and is handled specially by the console to send a special break signal to your application, and if your application doesn't handle it then it will be terminated. Another problem is that input from the console is normally line-based, and you only get input once the user has pressed the newline or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

A possible solution for the first problem is to use the [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to set a handler function to catch the signal, and in the handler tell the application that <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> has been pressed.

A solution for the both problems is to [change the console mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to not process <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>, and to disable the line based input.

Also note that normally <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> is used to copy selected content *to* the clipboard and not from, which is usually <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>.

---

But handling of the keystrokes is only a small part of the problem, as you then have to work with [the clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648709%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the actual copy-pasting.

Comment: Surely I explained it bad, sorry, but I only want to get (in any way) what is stored in the clipboard.